# Are humans the weakest race among all? Why are we only left?

Tags: vedas

Of course, Lord Krishna and Lord Rama are exceptions and i don't mean demi gods either but overall, like among Rakshas, Devas, Gandharva, Kinnar, Vanar, Garuda, etc. Humans are weakest. I have not seen any other race weaker.

So, why only humans are left today? Where are other species? Why does Lord take avatar in human form only since last three yugas?

Comment: Humans are the weakest because they don't have supernatural powers. All those races are celestial races with supernatural powers.

Comment: " why only humans are left today?" You are assuming that those other races don't exist now and which isn't true. Those are all non-physical beings and we can't see them under normal circumstances. Does not mean they don't exist anywhere.

Comment: Why cant we see other races? It wasn't like that always! Why now? And if you are gonna say that it's because of Kaliyug and humans are rotten now then why only only humans? Why other races are not affected by Kaliyug?